# How to copy ALL files, from root, to an external hard drive in opensuse 15.2

Tags: linux, rsync, backup, opensuse, file-copy

Good day everyone.

Since I'm going to format my laptop, I'm trying to copy all files, along with symlinks, hidden files and so on, starting from /

I launched this command

```
sudo rsync -avxHAXWS --numeric-ids --info=progress2 --exclude-from '/srv/www/exclude-list.txt' / /path/to/my/hd/
```

The command was executed without any errror. Unfortunately not all files/directories were saved: some of them did, others did not.

( Just to be clear: inside `/srv/www/exclude-list.txt` there is just 1 folder )

At the moment I'm on Opensuse 15.2

So I'd like to know what's the right command or if there are some other ways to copy all my files.

Thank you all

Comment: Is there any pattern to what's missing? The `-x` would prevent it from crossing fs boundaries; are you sure the missing files aren't on another?

Comment: @frabjous you are indeed right! I removed that flag and now it's working! Thank you so much!